# Child URL Query params shown with ; instead of &

Tags: url, nested, angular, angular2-routing

I am creating a nested route and when trying to access the link with params and query from the child routes it is shown as `http://localhost:3000/test/test/TestingId;param1=value1` instead of `http://localhost:3000/test/test/TestingId?param1=value1`

Here are my parent route definitions:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: RootComponent, name: 'RootCmp' },
  {path: '/test/...', component: NestedComponent, name: 'NestCmp', data: {isAdmin: true} }
])

@Component({
  selector: 'main-app',
  template:` 
      <h1>Using Router and Router Config</h1>
      <a [routerLink]="['RootCmp']">Home</a> | 
      <a [routerLink]="['NestCmp']">Nested Route Test</a> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink]
})
```

My child route definitions are like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: SecComponent, name: 'NestCmp', useAsDefault:true },
  {path: '/test/:id', component: SecComponent, name: 'NestChildCmp', data: {isAdmin: true} },
])

@Component({
  selector: 'child-app',
  template:` 
      <h1>Using Router and Router Config</h1>
      <a [routerLink]="['./NestCmp', {'param1': 'value1'}]">Nested Home</a> |
      <a [routerLink]="['NestChildCmp', { 'id': 'TestingId', 'param1': 'value1'}]">Nested Route Test</a> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink]
})
```

Comment: Seems like known issue. Thanks, closing this question. https://github.com/angular/router/issues/397

Comment: https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html

Answer (score 1):

`param1` is not defined in the path you are using in `@RouteConfig`. I am assuming this is an optional parameter and the final url you would be getting from the following code will be.

`http://localhost:3000/test/test/testingId`

or

`http://localhost:3000/test/test/testingId/value1`

Try this in your Child component

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: SecComponent, name: 'ChildCmp', useAsDefault:true },
  {path: '/test/:id', component: SecComponent, name: 'NestChildCmp1', data: {isAdmin: true} },
  {path: '/test/:id/:param1', component: SecComponent, name: 'NestChildCmp2', data: {isAdmin: true} },
])

@Component({
   selector: 'main-app',
   template:` 
     <h1>Using Router and Router Config</h1>
     <a [routerLink]="['./NestCmp', 'NestChildCmp1', {'id': 'testingId'}]">Nested Home</a> |
     <a [routerLink]="['./NestCmp', 'NestChildCmp2', { 'id': 'testingId', 'param1': 'value1'}]">Nested Route Test</a> 
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink]
  })
```

Also keep different name of different routes, example `NestCmp` is name of both parent and child route in your code.

Comment: No Gaurav, I tried different ways. `One parameter like you said works fine for one param definition`. However, I am not able to pass a query string from the definitions after parameter. The `same in the parent with the same type of definition works fine as a query string`.